# GLM rotates objects around origin and around of the object itself

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, transform, glm-math

I'm trying to rotate a bunch of objects on their x axis.

This is how I calculate an object's transform:

```
glm::mat4 GameObject::getTransform(float angle) {
  glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
  model = glm::translate(model, position);
  model = glm::rotate(model, angle, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
  model = glm::scale(model, scaleValue);
  return model;
}
```

I've tried to put the `translate`, `rotate`, `scale` functions into different order with no avail. Only strange behaviour.

This is how I iterate over objects and draw them:

```
for (auto row : objectRows) {
  for (auto object : row) {
    glm::mat4 model = object->getTransform(glfwGetTime());
    glm::mat4 mvp = projection * view * model;
    mainShader.setMat4("model", model);
    mainShader.setMat4("mvp", mvp);
    mainShader.setVec3("objectColour", object->colour);
    object->mesh.draw(mainShader);
  }
}
```

The vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;

out vec3 fragPos;
out vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 mvp;

void main()
{
    fragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
    normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(fragPos, 1.0f);
}
```

And the result:
[image: OpenGL/glm rotating bug]

As you can see the objects at the top rotate only around themselves and the lower other objects are the more they rotate around what I think is the world origin point?

I've read many similar looking posts explaining about the order of multiplying the matrices but nothing seems to help, and I can't help to think it is something stupidly simple that I'm overlooking.

Comment: If yo do `translate` and then `rotate` the object rotates around (0,0) of the object. If you do `rotate` and then `translate`, the object rotates around (0,0) of the world.

Comment: Try this order , first scale then rotate , then Translate

Comment: @Summit No. It has to be `T * R * S` or  `R * T * S`! The scale has to be first in any case.

Comment: @Rabbid76 As I've mentioned I have tried calculating the transform scale with `translate`, `rotate`, and `scale`  in different orders (all orders in fact).

Comment: @xlog As I mentioned it rotates around (0, 0, 0). Is (0, 0, 0) the center of the mesh respectively objects)? Or is (0, 0, 0) a corner point of the mesh respectively group of objects?

Comment: @Rabid76 What is being rendered here is a collection of cube objects, each with its own position. The first cube (top left on the grid) is at (0, 0, 0). Cubes to its right have an increasing x position value and cubes going down have decreasing y values.

Comment: Let me also add that the final effect I want to achieve is that the cubes in the grid independently move and rotate in each frame.

Comment: @xlog The issue is that (0, 0, 0) is not the center of a cube it is a corner point of a cube. Furthermore the cubes are distributed in positive x and y dir only. There are no cubes in the negative directions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205937/discussion-between-xlog-and-rabbid76).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the vertex shader.

```
void main()
{
    fragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
    normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(fragPos, 1.0f);
}
```

I accidentally was multiplying the model matrix twice. `fragPos` is a result of multiplying `model` with a vertex. Two lines below I multiply `mvp` with `fragPos`, so the calculation is `model * view * projection * model`.

To fix this I separated `mvp` and set each matrix as its own uniform in the shader and changed the line `gl_Position = mvp * vec4(fragPos, 1.0f);` to `gl_Position =  projection * view * vec4(fragPos, 1.0);`